# What is the maximum size of a uniform array that can be passed to a shader in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am using instanced rendering by passing an array of model view matrices. What is the maximum array size possible for a particular uniform?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This value will vary by hardware and implementation. I believe that

```c
int maxUniformVectors;
glGet(GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS, &maxUniformVectors);
```

should answer your question.

From the [docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGet.xml):

> This should return "the maximum number of four-element floating-point, integer, or boolean vectors that can be held in uniform variable storage for a vertex shader. The value must be at least 128.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the correct answer, actually. It sounds like what the OP is asking is what is the maximum _size_ of a uniform array that can be passed to a shader in iOS, not the maximum number of vectors. I believe this is _much_ lower than 128, somewhere around 7 or 8, as I've had issues with this in the past having to split large arrays into multiple smaller arrays.